# Rails_admin cant set locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, rails-i18n

I have API app and am using rails_admin with it.
Am trying to set default language to :nl for the app but to keep rails admin in English.

```
#application.rb
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :nl]
```

Was trying to intercept locale at Application controller but rails admin seems to never trigger it.

```
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
 if [RailsAdmin].include?(self.class.parent)
   I18n.locale = :en
 else
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure rails admin inherits from the application controller so your action is called.
In the latest(1.2.0) rails admin this can be configure in an initializer like so:

```
#/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'
end
```